# Unable to upload iOS app screen shots on iTunes connect

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

Hi i am trying to upload screenshots for an app but i am getting this error:

> "Screenshots and app previews for the largest display sizes of your app’s primary localization must be uploaded directly., Screenshots and app previews for the largest display sizes of your app’s primary localization must be uploaded directly."

Also on my account for 5.5 inch display **Choose Files** button is disabled. Please see the screen shot given below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving screenshot from simulator,

Go to Hardware display and scale to 100% and save screenshot.
Now your screenshots are scaled to the appropriate size and you can upload them

OR you can save screenshots directly from device.

Comment: problem is that Choose file button is disabled. I am unable to upload the screenshots.